# Inherit nearly all from a first function

Tags: javascript, oop

Hello I'm trying to make DRY code (not repeat code) from the a secondFunction that inherits NEARLY all the content from a firstFunction.

This would be the example of what I want but it's not DRY:

```js
function firstFunction(){
 
  this.arrayObjectsToElastic = ["hello1", "hello2"]
  this.anothervariable1= "anothervariable1"
  this.anothervariable2= "anothervariable2"
  this.targetVariableToRemove = "something"
  return [this.arrayObjectsToElastic]
}


function secondFunction(){
 
  this.arrayObjectsToElastic = ["hello1", "hello2"]
  this.anothervariable1= "anothervariable1"
  this.anothervariable2= "anothervariable2"
  
  return [this.arrayObjectsToElastic]
}
```

Therefore, I don't want to "inherit" in the secondFunction the targetVariableToRemove from the firstFunction because if so it'll crash in some other processes I'm running.

Comment: Since merely declaring a local variable does absolutely nothing of interest, this sample is a bit too abstract to really help you with in concrete ways. In general though, there is no such thing as "inheritance" for function bodies.

Comment: @deceze I've transform it into oop, maybe now it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like:

```
function secondFunction(){
    return firstFunction().concat(["newContent"]);
}
```